# OUT OF MEMORY error in MATLAB not resolved after changing the Virtual memory

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How can i handle OUT OF MEMORY problem in MATLAB? I changed the virtual memory to 20GB in drives C(where windows 8 is installed) and E(where MATLAB 2015a is installed). I have restarted the computer and run the code but i'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you positive the code does not run in an infinite loop or recursion or something, allocating more memory along the way?

Comment: I'm working on for 30M samples of signal. And i'm getting the error on multiplying it with another signal of 30M samples. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: After getting OUT OF MEMORY error, i got this on the command 'memory' ':
>>memory
Maximum possible array:     57 MB (6.016e+07 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    664 MB (6.960e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:   2793 MB (2.929e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   1910 MB (2.003e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.

Comment: I've increased the Java Heap Memory to maximum and given preference to MATLAB in the task manager too.I'm using a 32bit MATLAB setup on 64bit system.Can it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More Java Heap Memory is what you need, it's not about virtual memory available.

from your comment it seems you only have about  664 MB of Memory available for your arrays. Assuming your signal is one-dimensional, then those two 30M samples should take:

`30M * 2 * 8-Bytes = 480 MBytes`.

And if you have some copies of it, then your memory would be filled. Use the `whos` command to check each variable size. Clear each variable when you are done with it. Even if you are not running out of memory, clear those variables to make memory management easier for java -> faster for you.

Comment: what takes 8-Bytes to be stored?

Comment: @S.G.K , each double precision number takes 8-Bytes. you can see this using `whos` command or searching over web, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, length(yourVector) = 30e6? It might be too much for you to hold in memory. Loading the file(s) in chunks with fopen/fread could help. What kind of file is it?

```
dataType = 'float' ;  % data type
chunkSize = 1e4 ; % load in chunks
fid = fopen(pathToYouFile); frewind(fid); % Read file from the start
fprintf('Loading . . . '); % start notice
while ~feof(fid)    
    theData = fread(fid,[1 chunkSize],dataType); % load chunk
    % do yo thing
end
fprintf('Fini. ');  % all done
```

fclose(fid);